# Blocking signals on disabled widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qt-signals

I have a combo which is disabled, but adding an element to it will emit the `currentIndexChanged(int)` signal.

I expected signals to be naturally turned off when a widget is disabled, but it's not the case. I know there is `blockSignals(bool)`, but if there are many widgets whose signals must be "blocked when disabled", `blockSignals` would require a Boolean state for each widget.

How can I disable the signals sent by a widget when it is disabled (and not alter its `blockSignals` state)?

EDIT
To clarify: since this is a widget, user cannot interact with it when it's disabled, *but* some signals are emitted when altering the widget programmatically. In my case there are two interesting signals:
`currentIndexChanged(int)` and `activated(int)`

The problem in my code is that I sometimes alter the combo programmatically AND I wish it to emit a signal, and sometimes it's the user that alters the combo by interacting. That's why I am using `currentIndexChanged` and not `activated`.

In both cases, anyway, I don't want the signals to be emitted when widget is disabled.

Comment: But maybe you can still emit all signals, and in the slots just ignore them if emitting widget is not enabled?

Comment: @vahancho yes, could be a solution, but I hoped in something more structure in Qt, as this solution duplicates a lot of code for checking.

Comment: Well, from the other hand, if you make a widget disabled, why cannot you block its signals (blockSignals(true)) too?

Comment: I can, but I have to save the previous blocking state. Requires an extra variable (and it's not a big deal, but would be better if I didn't have to).

Comment: Also worth noting, what if the parent is disabled? `blockSignals(true)` could be a lot of pain in this case.

Comment: Do you mean all signals are user-interaction based? Would you say that's the case for something like QLocalSocket::stateChanged?  I think of user-interaction as a direct and immediate action from the user, such as clicking on a button.

Comment: By the way, you do know that `QComboBox` offers 2 signals for this? [`There are two signals emitted if the current item of a combobox changes, currentIndexChanged() and activated(). currentIndexChanged() is always emitted regardless if the change was done programmatically or by user interaction, while activated() is only emitted when the change is caused by user interaction`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#details).

Comment: @thuga yes, but I need both cases :)

Comment: As for the matter of user-interaction: no, I am talking about signals in general, not user-interaction based only. But also, I am talking about QWidgets's enabled status and not QObjects in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QComboBox` signals are user interaction based from end user point of view if you only have a `QComboBox` and nothing else as your question seems to imply.

I simply cannot reproduce the issue. I have just made a short program where I cannot get any of the QComboBox signals emitted since I cannot simply interact with the widget.

**Edit**: It might be a good idea to upate your question with more context for the casual readers, but based on further clarification in comments, yes, programatically it might be the case, but then signals might be useful to process programmatically, too, with corresponding slots, so it is not a major improvement if Qt blocks them automatically.

Luckily, the feature you wish to have is already available:

> [bool QObject::blockSignals(bool block)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals)
>
> If block is true, signals emitted by this object are blocked (i.e., emitting a signal will not invoke anything connected to it). If block is false, no such blocking will occur.
>
> The return value is the previous value of signalsBlocked().
>
> Note that the destroyed() signal will be emitted even if the signals for this object have been blocked.

If you want to do it for many widgets, create a simple function that you call instead of `myWidget->setDisabled(true);`:

```
inline bool disableAndBlockSignals(QWidget *widget)
{ 
    widget->setDisabled(true);
    return widget->blockSignals(true);
}
```

If you want to disable only some of them, say, `currentIndexChanged`, you can use [disconnect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) manually then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned in the post, I was already aware of `blockSignals` (and currently I'm using this feature to achieve what I need). The purpose of the post is to understand if there is a method to automatically block signals when a widget is disabled. Using `blockSignals` becomes a bit tedious when (like my case) there are many widgets to block.

Comment: I really hoped that a flag like `blockSignalsWhenDisabled(bool)` was present in `QWidget`s, but it seems there's none :P

Comment: @AkiRoss: `inline bool disableAndBlockSignals(QWidget *widget) { widget->setDisabled(true); return widget->blockSignals(true); }`

Comment: Eheh yes, but it's not the same I meant: with this function, I still have to store the bool, and it's not a general flag that I can apply to a widget when constructed... I'd have to call this function instead of `setEnabled` on my widget, which requires a bit of additional code. Anyway, I'm doing something similar to your suggestion right now.

Comment: @AkiRoss: subclass the widget and add a flag to the constructor. The Qt API cannot be cluttered by every little nuance since it would become more difficult to use then for the usual cases. Your case might be valid, but not common enough.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the only viable alternative :\ thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can disconnect signals with the `QObject::disconnect();` when you want to block them and then reconnecting them when you want to unblock them.

Comment: This is not very convenient option, because you have to remember all connections, to restore them back.

Comment: it is true that it is possible to write a catch-all connect/disconnect function, but then you reinvent blockSignals unless you only want to block some of them in which case this is technically a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the signals are the sole source of state information carried on to other objects. If you disable them, the other objects won't ever get any notification that the state was changed. This can cause bugs in the objects that depend on being informed of your widget's state.

There are at least two solutions:

1. Don't change the widget's state. You can certainly defer the update of the widget's contents until after it gets reenabled.
2. Create a proxy that monitors the originating widget's state, and queues up the signals (with compression) until the widget gets reenabled.

Due to those workarounds, your design may require a rework. Perhaps it'd be better if you could cope with signals from those disabled widgets. You should also evaluate whether disabling a widget doesn't break the user experience. What if the user wants to see the contents of a widget, but doesn't mean to change the current setting? A disabled widget in such a case is going too far. You can make you own, perhaps subclassed, widget, acting so that the control is not disabled, but the current element stays fixed. This could even be a separate object, applicable to any control - through judicious leverage of the user property.